# How to prevent dialog from disappearing? Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, popup

In this code I am displaying popup that have buttons, when button responsible for cancelation is clicked confirmation dialog shows up. I want the popup to disappear when clicked outside of it so I handle it like so:

```
  const popupRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const handleClickOutside = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    if (
      popupRef.current &&
      !popupRef.current.contains(event.target as Node)
    ) {
      onClose();
    }
  };
  

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, []);
```

`onClose` is callback that closes the popup. Now when button is clicked I create the dialog like so:

```
      {showCancelConfirmationDialog && 
      <CancelConfirmationDialog 
      onCancel={handleCloseDialog} 
      onConfirm={handleCancelReservation} 
      name={block.lessonWith} 
      time={chosenTime} 
      date={block.day} />}

  const handleCloseDialog = () => {
    console.log("closing");
    setShowCancelConfirmationDialog(false);
  }

  const handleCancelReservation = () => {
    console.log("block")
    block.isReserved = false;
    block.reservedBy = "notMe";
    onClose();
  }
```

Dialog code:

```
interface DeleteConfirmationDialogProps {
  onCancel: () => void;
  onConfirm: () => void;
  name: string;
}

const DeleteConfirmationDialog: React.FC<DeleteConfirmationDialogProps> = ({ onCancel, onConfirm, name }) => {
  return (
    <div className="delete-confirmation-dialog">
      <p className='delete-confirmation-dialog-p'>Te jazdy są zarezerwowane przez: {name} </p>
      <p className='delete-confirmation-dialog-p'>Czy na pewno chcesz je przesunąć i powiadomić o tym kursanta?</p>
      <button className='delete-confirmation-dialog-button' onClick={onConfirm}>Usuń i powiadom</button>
      <button className='delete-confirmation-dialog-button' onClick={onCancel}>Anuluj</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DeleteConfirmationDialog;
```

And now the problem is that wherever I click everything disappears because `useEffect` and `handleClickOutside` is triggered no matter what and I have no idea what it is happening. If I comment out this code it works fine. I tried adding another `popupRef` for the dialog but it didn't work. I also tried to control it via boolean when dialog is active but it also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best option would be to use a ready-made component, such as the `Dialog` of Material-UI.

You can find more information with good examples [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/).

Comment: It would probably work, but I would like to solve the issue and try to understand why is it like that

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your above code.

I think that there is some issues on this

```
  const handleClickOutside = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    if (
      popupRef.current &&
      !popupRef.current.contains(event.target as Node)
    ) {
      onClose();
    }
  };
```

Here is my new code.

```
const handleClickOutside = (event: MouseEvent) => {
  if (
     !popupRef.current ||
     popupRef.current.contains(event.target as Node)
   ) {
    return;
  }
  onClose();
};
```

Also you need to trigger `touchstart` event to close modal.

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
document.addEventListener('touchstart', handleClickOutside);

document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
document.removeEventListener('touchstart', handleClickOutside);
```

Let me know if you have any still issues.
I hope that my code is working for you. 
Thank you.

Comment: I just found the answer, and post it above, thank you for your help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, Simply add new useRef like so:

```
  const popupRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const cancelDialogRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const handleClickOutside = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    if (
      popupRef.current &&
      !popupRef.current.contains(event.target as Node)&&
      !cancelDialogRef.current?.contains(event.target as Node)
    ) {
      onClose();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, []);
```

and here wrap it into div

```
      <div ref={cancelDialogRef}>
      {showCancelConfirmationDialog &&
        <CancelConfirmationDialog
          onCancel={handleCloseDialog}
          onConfirm={handleCancelReservation}
          name={block.lessonWith}
          time={chosenTime}
          date={block.day} />}
      </div>
```

now it works correctly